# OOP Design Player and AI Controlled Unit. dynamic_cast?

Tags: c++

Lets say I have a Actor type, which can be any placeable object on my Game Level.
I also have Unit which is a child class of Actor. A Unit can be either a player or a AI controlled hero.

And Unit also got 2 child classes: Player (the player) and Hero (AI controlled unit).
In the Unit class, there will be movement info, rotation, and other general settings which will be needed for both Player and Hero. In the child classes AI will have different and more functions than the player.

Right now I'm facing the following problem:

A function only accepts Actor as parameter (e.g. `OnOverlap(Actor a*)`)
but `OnOverlap()` should only do something if it is a Unit class (hero or player).
Therefore I would need something like `instanceof()` from Java in C++.

A workaround would be either to use `dynamic_cast`, but I'm not sure if thats a good idea for performance. Or use virtual, but this won't work when Hero has more functions than Player.

Or should I attempt a whole new OOP design?

Comment: Use virtual, that's what it's for.  I don't follow your logic that it "won't work" if hero has more functions than pkayer.  With OOP sometimes you will use virtual, and sometimes (hopefully rarely) you have to downcast, using something like `dynamic_cast`

Comment: my engine actually provides a "GetClass" method: 
if (unit->GetClass()->IsChildOf(APlayerCharacter::StaticClass()))
but i'm still curious for other solutions :>

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that a `dynamic_cast` is [code smell](http://blog.codinghorror.com/code-smells/). Not necessary bad per se, but a sign that something might be going wrong with your design.

One of the important concepts in OOP is polymorphism: the idea that objects behave differently depending on their type, and that this behavior is *encapsulated*, hidden behind an interface. If you explicitely check the type of an object to change the logic you want to apply to it, then you're violating polymorphism.

Now virtual methods aren't that great either, they indeed incur runtime costs, and can sometimes bring too much complexity to the table. C++ makes `virtual` methods the exception, not the default, I believe for these very reasons.

One thing you should know is that virtual methods are only one kind of polymorphism, called dynamic polymorphism. There's another way to get different behaviors depending on a type that is less impeding for the runtime: static polymorphism, [AKA template metaprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming). But this isn't really helping on the complexity side.

Now what you really should do in this case is treat separate things separately. You probably want to have this `OnOverlap()` method on `Units` for a reason: let's say you're doing collision check on `Units` only, not all `Actors`. Then maintain a separate list of `Units`, and have that `OnOverlap()` method non-virtual on the `Unit` class. Thinking this way is often key.

Comment: At the moment the OnOverlap function is used for a Mesh. These function is predefined by my Engine, where the parameter must but the parent function "Actor". So if any Actor collides with the Mesh, the function is called. In this case for me i see no other solution, than getting the instance of the Actor object to know if its a player of just something else

Comment: @Sleicreider If this is your custom engine, I don't see what prevents you from changing `OnOverlap()`'s signature? If you can't for some reason, a workaround is to make sure you call this on `Units` only (once again, by having a dedicated list) and use a good'ol `static_cast`. If you do that, make sure you check the type at least in debug builds.

Comment: But yeah, this works in some cases, but doesn't in others, YMMV. Sometimes polymorphism *is* the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This technique is called [Run-Time Type Information (RTTI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information), and checking if the output of a dynamic_cast is NULL is a valid implementation.

Another method is to `#include <typeinfo>` and use `typeid(*a).name()` to get the string name of a's type.

Answer (score 0):

The need to use `dynamic_cast` is *often* (though not always) a sign that you have a design flaw. In this case, I think you do.

Without further comment on the overall design of the architecture you've described, I would say using virtual methods is the right approach. Have `OnOverlap` takes it's actor and call an `OnOverlapped` method on the actor, perhaps giving it a pointer to the thing executing the initial `OnOverlap` method (it's not clear from your question what that is(*)).

```
void X::OnOverlap (Actor * actor) {
  actor->OnOverlapped(this);
}
```

`OnOverlapped` is itself virtual. This allows you to "do the right thing" in the case of an actor unit, but do nothing or some other default behavior everywhere else. You are correct that in this case that means you can only work with the public API of `Actor`. You'd have to move anything requiring `Player`'s additional methods into the `Player` implementation of `OnOverlapped`. If you really think you cannot do that for some reason, you should perhaps consider an alternative design at a higher level (and may need to edit your question to provide more details about your architecture).

(*) My initial read of your question made me think `OnOverlap` is not a method of `Actor` already; that it was part of something unrelated. If it *is* part of `Actor`, you may be instead interested in a pattern called [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch), which can be used for this sort of "collision handling" type of problem, and is also a technique using dynamic dispatch (virtual)).

Answer (score 0):

> These function is predefined by my Engine, where the parameter must
>   but the parent function "Actor". So if any Actor collides with the
>   Mesh, the function is called. In this case for me i see no other
>   solution, than getting the instance of the Actor object to know if its
>   a player of just something else

A simple virtual function in the Actor base class can be a noop. Override it in Unit class, and specialize it even more in Hero and Player if needed. Non-Unit Actor's will call an empty method. Cleaner than RTTI and the instanceof idiom.

It is ok to have a default base implementation that expects to be overridden by specialized descendants. That is the point of abstract base classes, except in this case you are providing a default implementation that does nothing. The idea is that you are dispatching the "DoCollision" message (a virtual function in C++). You don't care which classes handle it or how. Just that the object has the DoCollision compile-time "interface" and that you dispatched it correctly.

Comment: Ok, but for the `Hero` and `Player` class? Ofc they share some functions which will do different things, therefore I would use `abstract` functions in `Unit`, but if `Hero` has an additional function, I would need to know if the `Unit` is a `Hero` to use this special function and then `cast` the `Unit` to `Hero

Comment: No, you don't have to cast it, you can call the special function from Hero's DoCollision function.